# Calling JPA findBy method multiple times

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, find-by-sql

I have a functionality where a list of A(Entity) objects is given which is being iterated to manipulate a functionality where in the iteration B(Entity)'s column value is fetched by C_ID and DATE multiple times(JPA method: `findByCIdAndDate`), there are possibilities that by the same C_ID and DATE are queried multiple times.  How do we approach this performance-wise?.

Is this ok to have this functionality because this could be handled by default Hibernate cache?

FYI: There is no caching applied to the application.

Comment: First, check if this is a performance issue. If yes, this can be handled by Hibernate cache. Just out of curiosity. Why do you have ID and Date? Isn't the ID unique?

Comment: I meant some other mapped id, not the primary key, let me edit it.

Comment: if you can cache the query results and want to just return those same results when the same parameters are used, that is called a query cache - caching in JPA/Hibernate usually refers to entity caches. Hibernate has a query cache (https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/performance-querycache.html ) built overtop of the entity cache. You'll need to look at the specifics of such a cache to see if it'll fit your application as there are side effects of caching you'll have to live with.